# What does '$path =~ s|/$||' do in perl?

Tags: perl, match

I find this piece of code in an opensource project. The path will be a UNIX path and passed as a parameter. I was wondering what the following code actually do for me :

```
$path =~ s|/$||;
```

Thanks!

****Update:**

Thanks for telling me the answer, however, I would like to know how the code rewrite in common regular expression matching will be?

I can't figure out the piece enclosed with vertical bar.

What is the second last vertical bar means? Thank you!

Comment: it strips off a trailing `/` char.

Comment: You can use a character other than `/` as the delimiter. In this case, `|` is used instead of `/` so that the `/` in the regular expression doesn't have to be escaped. Writing `s|/$||` avoids having to write `s/\/$//`.

Answer (score 1):

This code will remove a slash `/` found at the end of the string in `$path`. So, if you have

```
$path = "foo/bar/";
```

You will get

```
$path = "foo/bar";
```

This is a variation on the `s///` operator, where the delimiter has been changed from `/`to `|`, e.g. `s|||`. With the `s///` operator, you can exchange the slash `/` to almost any other character. For example

```
s!foo!bar!
s{foo}{bar}
s#foo#bar#
s?foo?bar?
```

The reason for changing delimiter is usually that such a character appears in the regex, which it does here. If your regex had not changed delimiter, it would look like this:

```
s/\/$//
```

Which is not as readable.

Comment: And if the string ends with a slash and a newline, it will remove both.